# SiteCore headless development material

Tags: sxa, jss

I am learning SiteCore headless development but I don't know what is the best source for headless

Comment: please refer to https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/19/sitecore-headless-development/index-en.html & https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/101/developer-tools/sitecore-headless-development.html for more details. Also therer are some videos for further digging at https://www.youtube.com/user/mastersitecore. Hope it helps.